# systemd slices even with low CPUShare heavily affect system responsiveness

Tags: linux, systemd, performance, tuning

I've created custom slice (so now I have 4 slices user, system, machine, important) and assigned huge number to `CPUShares`. System felt really unresponsive under high load in this slice, what seems to be logical considering enormous `CPUShares` value.

However later I've set `CPUShares` to really tiny value (`64` comparing to default `4096` for `user.slice` and `system.slice`) And to be honest system also felt quite unresponsive, maybe not that much but still it was really annoying. So as the result cpu load from `important.slice` was tiny comparing to other slices (around 11%) but everything felt terribly unresponsive.

What I mean by unresponsive is that the same app running in user.slice despite using much more CPU affected other processes in `user.slice` significantly less than the same process running in `important.slice`. For example:

Running Blender renderer in `user.slice` on all 8 cores under 100% load didn't make system feel unresponsive at all. *User experience* remained really good and PC remained capable of performing other tasks.

Running Blender renderer in `important.slice` with low `CPUShares` when utilizing only 11% CPU made whole system run painfully slow, even tty was lagging.

Of course `CPUAccounting` is enabled everywhere.